# Python Starlette Long Running Job

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, starlette

I want to add a long running job upon starting the server see below for my current implementation.

```
async def start_job():
    await long_job()

async def long_job():
    await task()
    await asyncio.sleep(settings.SLEEP)
      
app = Starlette(
        debug=settings.DEBUG, on_startup=[start_job]
    )
```

Its currently working but I'm not sure if its the right/correct way to do it any suggestions?